# JavaFX TableView ScrollBar value explanation

Tags: java, javafx

Could anyone explain what vertical scroll bar value means? For example, there is a table with 100 rows. View port can show only 10 rows. For example rows 26-35 are shown. What will be value of scroll bar and how it is calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all rows are the same height:

A scroll bar has a `min`, `max`, and `value`. If your viewport shows 10 rows and the table has 100 items, then it can be scrolled vertically a total of 90 rows (at one end, showing rows 1-10, and at the other, showing rows 91-100). If it shows 26-35 then it has scrolled 25 rows, so you will have

```
(value - min) / (max - min) = 25/90
```

or

```
value = min + 25*(max - min) / 90
```

The default `min` and `max` are `0` and `1`, respectively, so with those defaults this would be

```
value = 25 /90 = 0.277778
```